# Laravel Setting and Fetching time in UTC

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, laravel-4

I have set `'timezone' => 'UTC'` in app.php ... our database stores datetime in `UTC` ..We do not have access to database config... so we have to make changes from application end..
Currently its storing value just `2014-09-11 00:00:00` what ever i select from `calender`..ideally iam trying to fix this

when i insert date from `singapore UTC+8`  it should store as

```
'enterdate+8' 2014-09-11 08:00:00 in database..
```

similarly when i insert date from `japan utc+9` it should store

```
'enterdate+9' 2014-09-11 09:00:00 in database
```

But when a user search `2014-09-11 08:00:00` it should be converted to localtime ...something like `2014-09-11 00:00:00`

anyways to fix this in laravel 4 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use great `Carbon` that you have in place:

```
// for Eloquent
$dateFromDbInLocal = $model->created_at->tz('USER_TIMEZONE');

// for any timestamp
$dateFromDbInLocal = with(new Carbon\Carbon($timestampUTC))->tz('USER_TIMEZONE');

// other way around:
$dateInLocal = new Carbon\Carbon($timestampLocal, 'USER_TIMEZONE');
$dateInUtc = $dateInLocal->tz('utc');
```

Example:

```
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now(); // utc 2014-09-10 08:24:50

$japanUser = User::find($someId);
$japanUser->created_at->tz('Japan'); // 2014-09-10 17:24:50
```

You don't really need to convert anything upon saving, if your app is working in the same timezone as DB. Just do that in the presentation layer, so a user can read the date formatted to his timezone.

Comment: Yes it works but how do we enter values for `USER_TIMEZONE` ? It should detect the time zone automatically right?? how do we do that??

Comment: You must  provide user's timezone. You can store it in the user's table, detect it from the request data or whatever.